# ToolbarItem Icon stopped working

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, android-resources

My app has a ToolbarItem defined with an icon like this:

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Name="Refresh" Order="Primary" Text="Refresh" Icon="Refresh.png" Priority="0" Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}" />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

The image is in the Resources/drawable/Refresh.png, and this XAML was working fine in Xamarin Forms 2.3.4.247.

Suddenly, on the same version 2.3.4.247 this same XAML is failing with a null reference exception:

> {System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ResourceManager.GetId (System.Type
>   type, System.String propertyName) [0x0000d] in
>   C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\ResourceManager.cs:76
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ResourceManager.IdFromTitle
>   (System.String title, System.Type type) [0x00007] in
>   C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\ResourceManager.cs:70
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ResourceManager.GetDrawable
>   (Android.Content.Res.Resources resource, System.String name) [0x00000]
>   in
>   C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\ResourceManager.cs:42
>   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.NavigationPageRenderer.UpdateMenu
>   () [0x000f7] in
>   C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\NavigationPageRenderer.cs:747
>   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.NavigationPageRenderer.ToolbarTrackerOnCollectionChanged
>   (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs eventArgs) [0x00000] in
>   C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\NavigationPageRenderer.cs:715
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Internals.ToolbarTracker.EmitCollectionChanged ()
>   [0x00008] in
>   C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Internals\ToolbarTracker.cs:60
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Internals.ToolbarTracker.set_Target
>   (Xamarin.Forms.Page value) [0x00031] in
>   C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Internals\ToolbarTracker.cs:37
>   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.NavigationPageRenderer.OnElementChanged
>   (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ElementChangedEventArgs`1[TElement] e)
>   [0x000f2] in
>   C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\NavigationPageRenderer.cs:258
>   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].SetElement
>   (TElement element) [0x000f4] in
>   C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementRenderer.cs:196
>   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.IVisualElementRenderer.SetElement
>   (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element) [0x00027] in
>   C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementRenderer.cs:137
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Platform.CreateRenderer
>   (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element) [0x0001f] in
>   C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Platform.cs:289
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.Platform.AddChild
>   (Xamarin.Forms.Page page, System.Boolean layout) [0x00015] in
>   C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\Platform.cs:250
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.Platform.SetPage
>   (Xamarin.Forms.Page newRoot) [0x00089] in
>   C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\Platform.cs:239
>   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity.InternalSetPage
>   (Xamarin.Forms.Page page) [0x0001a] in
>   C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\FormsAppCompatActivity.cs:370
>   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity.AppOnPropertyChanged
>   (System.Object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs
>   args) [0x00012] in
>   C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\FormsAppCompatActivity.cs:321
>   at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.OnPropertyChanged (System.String
>   propertyName) [0x0000a] in
>   C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:136
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Element.OnPropertyChanged (System.String
>   propertyName) [0x00000] in
>   C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Element.cs:380
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Application.set_MainPage (Xamarin.Forms.Page value)
>   [0x0008b] in
>   C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Application.cs:90
>   at Intertain.Mobile.Custom.CustomMvxFormsPagePresenter.TryShowPage[T]
>   (MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxViewModelRequest request) [0x0005c] in
>   D:\Visual Studio\My
>   Projects\Intertain\Mobile\Intertain.Mobile\Intertain.Mobile\Custom\CustomMvxFormsPagePresenter.cs:76
>   }

Researching the problem I've discovered that I should be using lowercase names for resources, which I tried to fix, but no matter what I do I still get the same error.

I tried changing the XAML to OnPlatform:

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Name="Refresh" Order="Primary" Text="Refresh" Priority="0" Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}">
        <ToolbarItem.Icon>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource" Android="refresh.png" WinPhone="refresh.png" />
        </ToolbarItem.Icon>
    </ToolbarItem>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

Trying with the Icon value as "Refresh.png", "refresh.png", "refresh", and "Refresh", either with the image named Refresh.png or refresh.png in the drawable folder gives me the same error.

If I instead set the Icon property to blank on android:

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Name="Refresh" Order="Primary" Text="Refresh" Priority="0" Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}">
        <ToolbarItem.Icon>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource" Android="" WinPhone="refresh.png" />
        </ToolbarItem.Icon>
    </ToolbarItem>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

The page loads just fine, with no issue and I see the text "Refresh" and of course no icon.

So I'm convinced the problem is that it's not finding the image but I can't for the life of me figure out how to make it find it.

The image is set as AndroidResource, but I did try EmbeddedResource and None...

What the heck am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: Steve inspired me to try using a converter to bind to the resource, so I whipped this up:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    var source= ImageSource.FromFile(parameter.ToString());
    return source;
}
```

which I pass in a dummy binding and parameter to create the source:

```
<ToolbarItem Name="Refresh" Order="Primary" Text="Refresh" Icon="{Binding IsLoading, Converter={StaticResource IconSourceConverter}, ConverterParameter=refresh.png}" Priority="0" Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}" />
```

It is instantiated (I don't get a null reference error for the source value I return from the converter)

but after I return it, I get the same stupid error.

I officially give up and am just going to leave text instead the icon on android because having a crappy UI is better than having a broken one, and chalk it up to xamarin forms kind of still sucks and I need to get on with life.

Still if you have any ideas, I'm game to try again, but I'm through hacking at this.

Comment: Try to update Forms. Last version is already 2.3.4.247 You are a little behind :-)

Comment: oops i was looking at the wrong package. it turns out I am at 2.3.4.247, and the version that is working is ALSO on that same version. I'm updating the post to say this, sorry for the confusion on my part

Comment: can you provide a sample project and we/ll see if we can recreate and possibly fix the problem? it has to be something simple as it works in my projects

Comment: i'll see if i can recreate this in a blank project but i'm not hopeful, because like I mentioned for some reason an older version of the same project works just fine. i thought it was the nuget package for android appcompat but downgrading to match the working version didn't work either. but yes i'll dig more this weekend and report back with a sample if I can get one, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the item from code behind?

```
var searchToolbarItem = new ToolbarItem { Icon = AssetNames.SearchIcon };
ToolbarItems.Add(searchToolbarItem);
searchToolbarItem.SetBinding(MenuItem.CommandProperty, nameof(BookPageViewModel.OpenAppointmentsSearchCommand));
```

Where `AssetNames.SearchIcon` is:

```
public const string SearchIcon = "ic_search_white.png";
```

I've also noticed that you updated Xamarin.Forms to 1.2? That package version is from July 2014.

If that is the case, try the same with:
**Xamarin.Forms 2.3.4.247**

**Also delete the bin/obj folders and rebuild the project!**

Comment: i'll give this a try but now that i discovered they're both on the same version of forms (updated the original post, I was looking at the wrong package) I'm going to do a full diff against the two and see if I can spot the difference. will report back, thanks!

Comment: Try and avoid doing anything in the code behind, if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it:

View

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Icon="{Binding AddIcon}" Command="{Binding AddCommand}" />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

View Model

```
public ImageSource AddIcon => "ic_add.png";
```

The icon is in Resources\drawable\ic_add.png and has a build action of AndroidResource.

Make sure the filename and the name in the view model are both lower case.

Comment: this is an intriguing idea but I can't put this in my viewmodel because the VMs are not in the same library and so I can't reference Xamarin Forms objects in them. But it did give me the idea to try creating the binding via a converter... which also didn't work (I suspect if I could try what you're suggesting, I would get the same result as well). I'm giving up for now and just going to show text instead of an icon, but thank you for your input!